# How to find length of JSON?

Tags: json

This is my JSON array and how i can find JSON array length.

```
{"quizlist":[
    {
        "question":"lion.png",
        "option":"lion"
    },
    {
        "question":"tiger.png",
        "option":"tiger"
    },
    {
        "question":"cheetah.png",
        "option":"cheetah"
    },  
]}
```

Comment: what did you try and in which language ?

Comment: Convert your JSON string to JS object and then find the length `var jsObj = JSON.parse(JSON_String);` and length like `jsObj.length`

Answer (score -1):

In your case, it looks like a JS Object already.

So, simply use

```js
var jsObj = {
  "quizlist": [{
    "question": "lion.png",
    "option": "lion"
  }, {
    "question": "tiger.png",
    "option": "tiger"
  }, {
    "question": "cheetah.png",
    "option": "cheetah"
  }, ]
}

alert(jsObj.quizlist.length)
```

Comment: Of course it looks like a JS object, that is what JSON means. Also you assume the OP is using javascript, never make such assumptions. Wait with answering until that is made clear

Comment: JSON is a `string` not an `object`

Comment: @Ritave: what else do you expect if an array has 3 objects?

Comment: *JSON is a string not an object* yet in your answer you assume it is an object